# Has anyone used slow rise foam insulation?

Tags: insulation, spray-foam

Has anyone used slow rise foam insulation? Here is a link:

https://sprayfoamkit.com/products/slow-rise-spray-foam/

My house isn’t insulated (older houses in Japan rarely are) and I’d prefer not to tear down walls to add insulation. That said, buying enough of this stuff to do my house would cost a pretty penny so I might be better off tearing down drywall and doing it the old fashioned way. I was hoping to hear everyone’s thoughts.

Best, Jay